# Include header file or cpp file

Tags: c++

I have a class.h file and a class.cpp file that has the implementations of methods in class.h.
The class.cpp has an #include < class.h> statement. In my main.cpp, should I include < class.h> or < class.cpp>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the ".h" file (Header file).
A header file is a file which contains the function declarations and macro definitions to be shared between the source files ".cpp".